# UILabel is not showing values from the UITableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

Sorry guys its me again.

In my project i used `UITableview` for showing weather.so, I need to show the first row text to `UILabel` without any button action or watever. I just want cell text to UILabel without any action.

**ex:**
   In the **tableview** first cell showing text as "Lovely IOS"
I want to show the same text to UILABEL without any action. I took `UILabel` in the xib.
Thanks in advance

Any sample code please.

Answer (score 1):

you only set action for particular cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  if (indexPath.row == 1){
 //set action for cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` equate

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
 LabelName.text= cell.textLabel.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the data for your cell so what's a big to `UIlabel` .You just need to set the same text there.
**Updated**:-

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
```

you will get the text.

Comment: But i took 3 UIlabels in xib. if cell1 has text like "OBJ"

Comment: Label 1 = OBJ, Label 2 = LAA , LABEL 3 = lol ... . like that ,,,,

Comment: you want it for only first label? see you label text to cell or vice versa??

Comment: so you all three label text to cell rite?

Comment: i want to show the tableview's first three cells content to individual uilabels. cell1.text = label1.text, cell2.text = label2.text..... like that...

Comment: sorry for asking... where can i paste it

Comment: Here we can help you by solution ,how do it you need to figure out.If answer is valid then please vote up.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this either you add add UILable or set the text to he cell.textLabel.text in the following method.
`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`